# How to modify already existing chart axis (min, max) values, based on a cell, that will change values over time on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Meanwhile, i was trying to modify my chart "Title" based on cell value, that will change depending on gender of a person (male, female). Also i want to modify max value of vertical axie, based on a cell value that will change depending on person weight input. But I'm not even getting closer because of this error I'm getting on line 185, just driving me crazy!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i just figured it out, the error on line 185 was Chrome browser related, and my another question i resolved by storing a cell value to the LocalString(); line 184, will be doing the same for axis!

[image]